# Fancybox 3 ajax load image gallery

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox-3

[Fancy box *3* documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/) gives little examples regarding its AJAX functionality. I want to be able to click a button and load a "gallery" consisting of images loaded from an ajax response.

An example I found (last one on [this](https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/WjVXyx?editors=1000) page) requires hard-coding the image paths of the gallery in a hidden div; this is fine, but I rather reduce page load time by loading with AJAX.

I found something that looked [promising](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/) but I'm not sure how to implement ajax into it. Any ideas?

```js
$.fancybox.open([
    {
        src  : '1_b.jpg',
        opts : {
            caption : 'First caption'
        }
    },
    {
        src  : '2_b.jpg',
        opts : {
            caption : 'Second caption'
        }
    }
], {
    loop : false
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Turns out it was super simple:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/neou_cms/test/ajax_resp',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.fancybox.open(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

where AJAX response is:

```json
[{"src":"\/images\/uploads\/projects\/207002523\/m_207002523_1.jpg"},
 {"src":"\/images\/uploads\/projects\/207002523\/m_207002523_2.jpg"},
 {"src":"\/images\/uploads\/projects\/207002523\/m_207002523_3.jpg"}, 
 {"src":"\/images\/uploads\/projects\/207002523\/m_207002523_4.jpg"}]
```

You can even add in captions and optional thumbs as long as you follow this syntax:

```js
    {
        src  : '1_b.jpg',
        opts : {
            caption : 'First caption'
        }
    },
```

Codeigniter code:

```php
$this->load->model('backend/images_model');
$query = $this->db->get_where('projects', array('id' => '207002523'));
$images = $this->images_model->get_images($query->row()->images);
$output = array();
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $output[] = array('src' => $image['main']);
}
echo json_encode($output);
exit;
```

**If you already have one image in the href and and want to load more onto it when fancybox opens, you can do:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
        loop: false,
        onInit: function (instance) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/neou_cms/test/ajax_resp',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, src) {
                        instance.createGroup({
                            type: 'image',
                            src: src
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

## Little correction for the latest version of fancybox:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    loop: false,
    onInit: function (instance) {
      let id_album = $("[data-fancybox]").attr('id');
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './neou_cms/test/ajax_resp',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          $.each(data, function (item) {
            instance.addContent({
              'type': 'image',
              'src': item.src
            });
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: ```TypeError: instance.createGroup is not a function```, How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Yes! After reading carefully the documentation, I noticed that the `.createGroup` was substitute by `.addContent`

Comment: if you want you can plop an answer in here so the next person isn't confused.

Comment: @Alex thats a great help. thanks. One question. In your first approach where you used  `$.fancybox.open(data);` how can i trigger the same with some custom options?

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps in the ajax gallery:

1. Link to ajax gallery.
2. Construct your gallery in a different url.

**Link to ajax gallery:**

If you look at the documentation again (ajax part):

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#ajax

It states that you can easily link to a ajax gallery (no javascript required)
using `data-type="ajax"` and `data-src="my_page.com/path/to/ajax/"` for your ajax content

```
<a data-fancybox data-type="ajax" data-src="my_page.com/path/to/ajax/" href="javascript:;">
    AJAX content
</a>
```

After you create a link to the gallery now you can move on to setting up the ajax gallery in another url.

**Construct your gallery in a different url:**

In your separate url (`my_page.com/path/to/ajax/`) where you intend to keep all your gallery images, you just need to set up it up like how a normal fancybox gallery should be.

Example:

```
<div>
    <a data-fancybox="ajax-gallery-1" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7367/16426879675_e32ac817a8_b.jpg" title="Codirosso spazzacamino (Massimo Greco _Foligno)"><img width="160" height="106" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7367/16426879675_e32ac817a8_m.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a data-fancybox="ajax-gallery-1" href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5612/15344856989_449794889d_b.jpg" title="Morning Twilight (Jose Hamra Images)"><img width="160" height="106" src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5612/15344856989_449794889d_m.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a data-fancybox="ajax-gallery-1" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7289/16207238089_0124105172_b.jpg" title=" (Eric Goncalves (cathing up again!))"><img width="160" height="106" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7289/16207238089_0124105172_m.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a data-fancybox="ajax-gallery-1" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8568/16388772452_f4d77a92c7_b.jpg" title="Arctic Paradise (Tom Draxler)"><img width="160" height="106" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8568/16388772452_f4d77a92c7_m.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a data-fancybox="ajax-gallery-1" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7308/15783866983_27160395b9_b.jpg" title="Rodeo Dusk (_JonathanMitchellPhotography_)"><img width="160" height="106" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7308/15783866983_27160395b9_m.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    <a data-fancybox="ajax-gallery-1" href="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2880/10346743894_0cfda8ff7a_b.jpg" title="Les papillons ont du chagrin (JMS')"><img width="160" height="106" src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2880/10346743894_0cfda8ff7a_m.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

There is an ajax request example in FancyBox3 website as well, if you visit http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/, scroll to the part where it says **Ajax request**, you can see how the developer set up his gallery and how he display his gallery in a different url http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/ajax.php?v=1508722146.

Comment: I saw both examples you posted. However, it's not so much a gallery as it is a modal with click able images. What I'm talking about is more along the lines of the first example given on the fancy box website. If you click one image you see you can access the next images down the line. Except what I want to achieve is not having those images hard-coded but loaded via Ajax. Make sense?

Comment: Got it, which mean you want to input your gallery content completely using javascript and kept the other html separate am I right? In this case I don't think is possible as fancyBox will require you to trigger `href:'_'`for it to works. The example with thumbnails that you are seeing on the site are using the hardcoded method as well as the gallery can't trigger on its on. Even if you trigger the gallery by default the layout and mechanism won't be the same anymore. Is there any reason why you want to load through ajax?

Comment: i found the solution!

Comment: Can you post your solution here and would help others in future